# UPDATE table SET related_id=NULL WHERE related_id doesn't exist in related table

Tags: mysql

I need to update ***`table`*** and set ***`table`***.**`related_id`** (column that "binds" the table with ***`related table`***) to `NULL` where the ***`table`***.**`related_id`** doesn't exist in the ***`related_table`*** as ***`related_table`***.**`id`**.

example:

```
TABLE:
----------------------
id | name | related_id
----------------------
1  | aaa  | 15
2  | bbb  | 36
3  | ccc  | 7
4  | xxx  | 43

RELATED_TABLE:
----------
id | name
----------
9  | ddd
15 | eee
7  | fff
```

The query I need is supposed to update ***`table`*** like that:

```
TABLE:
----------------------
id | name | related_id
----------------------
1  | aaa  | 15
2  | bbb  | NULL
3  | ccc  | 7
4  | xxx  | NULL
```

(because **`id`** 36 and 43 doesn't exist in ***`related_table`***)

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 t
SET related_id = NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM related_table WHERE id = t.related_id)
```